# Tester Program Errors

Tags: java, oop

I have written a program and tester for said program, however when i compile the tester i get some errors (Shown Below) does anyone understand why i get these errors?

Main Code -

```
package com.date.example;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Student {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Student student = new Student("Charles");
    }

    private String forName;
    private String surName;
    private String studentID;
    private String degreeScheme;

    //This is the Constructor of the 
    public Student(String forName) {
        this.forName = forName;
    }

    public Student() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    //Assign the surname of the student 
    public void stuSurname(String stuSurname) {
        surName = stuSurname;
    }

    //Assign the student ID to the student
    public void stuID(String stuID) {
        studentID = stuID;
    }

    //Assign the Degree of the Student
    public void stuDegree(String stuDegree) {
        degreeScheme = stuDegree;
    }

    //Print the student details
    public void printStudent() {
        System.out.println("Forname:" + forName);
        System.out.println("Surename:" + 
surName);
        System.out.println("Student ID:" + 
studentID);
        System.out.println("Degree Scheme:" + 
degreeScheme);
    }

    // setter
    public void setForName(String forName) {
        this.forName = forName;
    }

    // getter
    public String getForName() {
        return forName;
    }
}
```

Tester Program -

```
package com.date.example;
import java.io.*;

public class StudentTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*create three new objects using constructor*/
    Student stuOne = newStudent1();
    Student stuTwo = newStudent2();
    Student stuThree = newStudent3();

    //Invoking Methods for Each object Created
    stuOne.setForName("James");
    stuOne.stuSurname("Smith");
    stuOne.stuID("0987");
    stuOne.stuDegree("Computer Science");

    stuTwo.setForName("Vanessa");
    stuTwo.stuSurname("Peach");
    stuTwo.stuID("0988");
    stuTwo.stuDegree("Mathematics");

    stuThree.setForName("George");
    stuThree.stuID("0989");
    stuThree.stuDegree("English");
//Invoking the printStudentmethod.
    stuOne.printStudent();
    System.out.println("\n");
    stuTwo.printStudent();
    System.out.println("\n");
    stuThree.printStudent();

   }
 }
```

this is what the code was written for  -

The class Student should contain a constructor, appropriate getters and setters, and the usual
string methods. Compile the java source to obtain a .class file and then write a tester class which
creates three instances of Student. For this exercise, supply student details as hard-coded
parameters. As always, ensure that your test program provides 100% method coverage.

and then this is the compile error that i get -

```
TheRealFawcett:Lab8 therealfawcett$ javac StudentTest.java
StudentTest.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
    Student stuOne = newStudent1();
                 ^
  symbol:   class Student
  location: class StudentTest
StudentTest.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
    Student stuOne = newStudent1();
                 ^
  symbol:   method newStudent1()
  location: class StudentTest
StudentTest.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    Student stuTwo = newStudent2();
                 ^
  symbol:   class Student
  location: class StudentTest
StudentTest.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    Student stuTwo = newStudent2();
                 ^
  symbol:   method newStudent2()
  location: class StudentTest
StudentTest.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
    Student stuThree = newStudent3();
                   ^
  symbol:   class Student
  location: class StudentTest
StudentTest.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
    Student stuThree = newStudent3();
                   ^
  symbol:   method newStudent3()
  location: class StudentTest
6 errors
TheRealFawcett:Lab8 therealfawcett$
```

if anyone understands why im getting these errors the help would be much appreciated, im new to java and this is as far as i got.

Comment: Where do you define `newStudent1()`, `newStudent2()`, or `newStudent3()` in your code?

Comment: try replacing all those `Student stuOne = newStudent1();` to `new Student();`.
Also try using a Junit test or even commenting out the main in student as you now have 2 mains (might cause problems later)

Comment: Also, if you're trying to call a constructor, this isn't the proper way to do it.

Comment: [Constructors in Java tutorial](https://www.studytonight.com/java/constructor-in-java.php)

Answer (score 2):

Probably because you are inventing your very own Java syntax:

```
Student stuOne = newStudent1();
```

Should be:

```
 Student stuOne = new Student();
```

Just like you do in your **main** method in the Student class.

Beyond that, the real answer is: don't write so much code, to then in the end run the compiler. Write only a few lines, just enough so you think "this should compile". Then run the compiler. Fix all bugs. Write a few more lines. And so on.

Beyond that, the real issue here might be that you don't understand the somehow complicated rules that need to be followed when using javac to compile classes that come within packages. I suggest to carefully read this [tutorial](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/21/using-javac-and-java-commands-to-compile-and-launch-java-programs/) for example.

Comment: i changed these in my code however i still get the same compile errors

Comment: i have no idea what that meant

Comment: is there anywhere you can see in the code i posed that this issues would be?

Comment: @CallumFawcett I enhanced my answer a bit. But please understand: this here is not a free tutor service where people help you getting through all the steps of your homework. We give you hints where/what to research, and then it is up to you to *apply* what you where told here. And just to be able to help you, you would need to lay out your directory structure and where exactly you call what, and what maybe your classpath setup is, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

2 Things that is mistakes that i look at:

1. Actually to create an object in the class you must used the class object which means **StudentTest** instead of Student that will be **StudentTest** stuTwo = newStudent2(); , if you not used the StudentTest , that is Student, where are supposed the object creation originated? if you want to used the object from main class? you must used the inheritance to get the object, otherwise the new object creation will be no reference to it. That is supposed the problem refer to new object creation cannot find its symbol.
2. **newStudent()**; -> should be -> **new Student()**;

Conclusion to used the main class object should used the **inheritance** method. Please find the tutorial about the **Inheritance**